# Get dataframe rows where every T sequence of columns there's 1 N times

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matrix

How to get the rows of a Dataframe that in **every sequence** of 5 columns there is **at least** 3 times the number one?
The dataframe filled with 1's and 0's (no missing values).

Example:
[image]

Also, a fast approch will be helpful due to millions of lines and tens of cols I need to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a rolling sum width a width of 5, look at all columns from the 5th to the end and select them if the values are always 3 or above:

```
rolling_sum = df.rolling(5, min_periods=1, axis=1).sum()
select = (rolling_sum.iloc[:, 4:] >= 3).all(axis=1)

In [92]: df
Out[92]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0
3  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1
4  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1
5  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0

In [94]: (df.rolling(5, min_periods=1, axis=1).sum().iloc[:, 4:] >= 3).all(axis=1)
Out[94]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: A simple way would be to set all values different from 1 to 0 (`df[df != 1] = 0`) and then run the same algorithm. Perhaps do it on a copy of `df` to keep the original values.

Answer (score 2):

Reshape underlying array data to `3D` such that the last axis has `5` elements each representing the blocks of `5` each and then sum along that axis to give us sum for each of those blocks and finally use `any` reduction along the second axis which represents each row from the original dataframe -

```
df['result'] = (df.values.reshape(-1,df.shape[1]//5,5).sum(2)>=3).any(1)
```

For performance, you might want to work with the boolean array :`df.values==1` instead of `df.values`.

Sample run -

```
In [41]: df
Out[41]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1
2  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1
3  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1
4  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0
5  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1
6  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1

In [42]: df['result'] = (df.values.reshape(-1,df.shape[1]//5,5).sum(2)>=3).any(1)

In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  result
0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1   False
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1    True
2  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1    True
3  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1    True
4  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0    True
5  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1    True
6  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1   False
```

If the number of cols isn't a multiple of `5`, we can use `np.add.reduceat` -

```
idx = np.arange(0,df.shape[1],5)
df['result'] = (np.add.reduceat(df.values, idx, axis=1)>=3).any(1)
```

Timings on `millions rows and tens of cols` -

```
In [99]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = (np.random.rand(1000000,20)>0.6).astype(int)
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(a)

# Solution from this post
In [101]: %timeit (df.values.reshape(-1,df.shape[1]//5,5).sum(2)>=3).any(1)
10 loops, best of 3: 65.3 ms per loop

# @w-m's soln
In [102]: %timeit (df.rolling(5, min_periods=1, axis=1).sum().iloc[:, 4:] >= 3).all(axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 8.04 s per loop
```